# Type is not assignable to type 'GetVerificationKey' in express-jwt.(using auth0)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express-jwt

I'm build an auth0 implementation according to [here](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/architecture-scenarios/spa-api/api-implementation-nodejs) using a combination of express-jwt and jwks-rsa.
However, an error like the below occurred and the tsc can't finish properly.

```
Error:(102, 5) TS2322: Type 'SecretCallbackLong | GetVerificationKey' is not assignable to type 'Secret | GetVerificationKey'.
  Type 'SecretCallbackLong' is not assignable to type 'Secret | GetVerificationKey'.
    Type 'SecretCallbackLong' is not assignable to type 'GetVerificationKey'.
```

My code is blow.

```js
import {expressjwt} from "express-jwt";
import * as jwksRsa from "jwks-rsa";


const checkJwt = expressjwt({
    secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({ //<--The error occurred in here.
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `**************************`
    }),

    audience: '*****************',
    issuer: '*******************',
    algorithms: [ 'RS256' ],
});
```

The type error occurred in the `secret` value in the options setting of `expressjwt`.
The code above is almost a copy of [here](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/architecture-scenarios/spa-api/api-implementation-nodejs).
So, I can't figure out the solution to this problem.
This is the first time of used auth0.
Anyone who can solve this problem?

typescript: 4.7.4
express: 4.18.1
jwks-rsa: 2.1.4
express-jwt: 7.7.5

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can explicitly type the *secret* parameter as shown here: https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt/issues/288

```
import jwksRsa from 'jwks-rsa';
import { expressjwt, GetVerificationKey } from 'express-jwt';


const checkJwt = expressjwt({
    secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({ //<--The error occurred in here.
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `**************************`
    }) as GetVerificationKey,

    audience: '*****************',
    issuer: '*******************',
    algorithms: [ 'RS256' ],
});
```